# "Guide for" or "guide of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation

I am struggling with the correct preposition going after guide. Which sentence is correct? "that dog served as a guide for blind people" or "that dog served as a guide of blind people".

Answer (score 2):

*Guide* generally takes either *for* or *to* as its prepositional follower.

*For* is used to indicate users, as in [*The Guide for the Perplexed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guide_for_the_Perplexed)

*To* indicates subjects, as in [*The Annenberg Guide to the U.S. Constitution*](http://www.annenbergclassroom.org/page/a-guide-to-the-united-states-constitution).

*Guide of* is found, but is currently much less common as this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guide%20to%2C%20guide%20for%2C%20guide%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cguide%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cguide%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cguide%20of%3B%2Cc0) illustrates.

Comment: +1 for referencing Maimonides, especially in that work.

Comment: In the context you mention the use is clearer. However, I am not sure whether there are subtle differences in meaning when you refer to someone or something moving guided by something as for instance in "the device is used as a guide for/of submarines"

Comment: @Juan I think the more common usage in AmE to describe devices that a submarine relied upon to navigate would be *a guide **for** submarines*.

Answer (score 0):

'For' is a good relation to use here.  'Of' would only mean that the dog belonged to the person, rather than served the person.  'To' would imply that the dog was leading something else to the person.